# Selectable input overflows screen when opening

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have created a selectable (datetime) input by hand. I'm having a issue when opening the selectable in smaller screens, it seems to overflow the content to the right:
[image]

This is the code for the 3 pickers, all of them open a selectable frame:

```
import React, { memo, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { CalendarIcon, ClockIcon, WorldIcon } from 'src/assets/icons'
import Calendar from 'src/components/Calendar/Calendar'
import moment from 'moment'
import { generateMeetingTimes } from 'src/constants'
import { default as momentTimezone } from 'moment-timezone'
import { UseFormReturn } from 'react-hook-form'

export interface DateTimeInputProps {
  form: UseFormReturn<any>
  hasError?: string
  className?: string
}

const DateTime = ({ form, hasError, className }: DateTimeInputProps) => {
  const date = form.getValues('when.date')
  const time = form.getValues('when.time')
  const offset = form.getValues('when.offset')

  const timezoneNames = momentTimezone.tz.names()
  const timezoneArray = timezoneNames.map((timezone) => {
    const abbreviation = moment.tz(timezone).zoneAbbr()
    return `${timezone} (${abbreviation})`
  })

  const [timezonePicker, setTimezonePicker] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [datePicker, setDatePicker] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [timePicker, setTimePicker] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const divRef = useRef<any>(null)

  const meetingDefaultTimes = useMemo(() => {
    return generateMeetingTimes()
  }, [])

  const toggleDatePicker = () => {
    setTimezonePicker(false)
    setTimePicker(false)
    setDatePicker(!datePicker)
  }

  const toggleTimePicker = () => {
    setTimezonePicker(false)
    setDatePicker(false)
    setTimePicker(!timePicker)
  }

  const toggleTimezonePicker = () => {
    setTimePicker(false)
    setDatePicker(false)
    setTimezonePicker(true)
  }

  const handleTime = (time: string) => {
    form.setValue('when.time', time)
    setTimePicker(false)
  }

  const handleOffset = (offset: string) => {
    form.setValue('when.offset', offset)
    setTimezonePicker(false)
  }

  const handleDate = (date: Date) => {
    console.log('called')
    form.setValue('when.date', date)
    setDatePicker(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event: any) => {
      if (divRef.current && !divRef.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        setTimezonePicker(false)
        setTimePicker(false)
        setDatePicker(false)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  }, [divRef])

  return (
    <div
      ref={divRef}
      className={`relative px-2 w-96 min-w-58 h-h-input flex bg-primary ${hasError ? 'border-error' : 'border-input-border'} border-1 rounded-input bg-transparent items-center ${className}`}
    >
      <span className="absolute top-0 -translate-y-1/2 text-placeholder pointer-events-none left-2.5 ease-linear duration-150 bg-background font text-[12px] px-[4px]">
        When
      </span>

      <div className="relative flex-[0.6] mr-2 h-10 flex bg-gray items-center justify-center rounded-input cursor-pointer  z-10">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={date && moment(date).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}
          className="w-full bg-gray outline-none text-center"
          onClick={toggleDatePicker}
          {...(form.register('date') as any)}
        />
        {!date && (
          <CalendarIcon
            fill={'grey'}
            width={22}
            height={22}
            className="absolute w-full left-0 right-0 pointer-events-none"
          />
        )}
        {datePicker && (
          <div className="absolute top-14 z-10">
            <Calendar
              selectedDate={date}
              setSelectedDate={(date: Date) => handleDate(date)}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div
        className="relative px-[6px] h-10 flex bg-gray items-center justify-items-center rounded-input mr-2 cursor-pointer flex-[0.4]"
        ref={divRef}
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          value={time}
          className="w-full bg-gray outline-none text-center"
          onClick={toggleTimePicker}
          {...(form.register('time') as any)}
        />
        {!timePicker && !time && (
          <ClockIcon
            fill={'grey'}
            width={22}
            height={22}
            className="absolute w-full left-0 right-0 pointer-events-none"
          />
        )}
        {timePicker && (
          <div className="border-input-border border-1 absolute top-0 left-[-15px] flex flex-col items-start rounded-input right-[55px] mt-56px max-h-56 overflow-y-scroll z-10 bg-background w-[120px] z-10 scrollbar-custom">
            {meetingDefaultTimes.map((option, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="hover:bg-primary hover:text-white w-full p-2 rounded-input cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleTime(option)
                }}
              >
                <span>{option}</span>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="relative flex-[0.4] px-4 h-10 flex bg-gray items-center justify-center rounded-input cursor-pointer">
        <input
          value={offset}
          className="w-full bg-gray outline-none text-center"
          onClick={toggleTimezonePicker}
          {...(form.register('timezone') as any)}
        />
        {!offset && (
          <WorldIcon
            fill={'grey'}
            width={22}
            height={22}
            className="absolute w-full left-0 right-0 pointer-events-none"
          />
        )}
        {timezonePicker && (
          <div className="border-input-border border-1 absolute top-0 left-[-15px] flex flex-col items-start rounded-input right-[55px] mt-56px max-h-56 overflow-y-scroll z-10 bg-background w-[280px] z-10 scrollbar-custom">
            {timezoneArray.map((timezone, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="hover:bg-primary hover:text-white w-full p-2 rounded-input cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleOffset(timezone)
                }}
              >
                <span>{timezone}</span>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default memo(DateTime)
```

Comment: It seems you are missed adding the code of the component before the `return`. Could you provide enough code for a working example please?

Comment: I have updated with the hole component